# format of Windows registry export file

Tags: windows, format, export, registry

I'm confused about the following: When I view a file created via registry export in Notepad, the content is human-readable. When I view the same file with any other text editor, I see a lot of unprintable characters. I posted a screenshot here: http://phillipmfeldman.org/photos

(I would like to write a Python script that generates a registry file that can be imported
into Windows, but can't do this without understanding the format of the file.)

Comment: The file looks like it was exported using UTF-16 with a BOM.

Comment: Per Wikipedia: "In UTF-16, a BOM (U+FEFF) may be placed as the first character of a" file or character stream to indicate the endianness (byte order) of all the 16-bit code units of the file or stream."  When I look at the file with a hex editor, the first two characters are FFFE, which is slightly discrepant from what was expected.  i suppose that I should be OK if I replicate that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The file format is UTF-16 (two octets per character).
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16